# Java Program for Binary Card Trick

Tags: java, binary-data

I want to print in

Card 1

all the numbers from 1 to 63 whose binary conversion has last digit as 1. 
for example  1=01 ,3=11 ,5=101 ,7 =111...and so on

Card 2

all the numbers from 1 to 63 whose binary conversion has 2nd last digit as 1.
for example 2=10 3 =11 6=110 7=111 and so on
.
.
.

Card 6

all the numbers from 1 to 63 whose binary conversion has first digit as 1
for example : 32 = 100000 33 =100001 and so on

I tried the following logic to convert decimal into binary

```
    public void printBinaryFormat(int number)
    {
        int binary[] = new int[25];
        int index = 0;
        while(number > 0){
        binary[index++] = number%2;
        number = number/2;
    }
    for(int i = index-1;i >= 0;i--){
        System.out.print(binary[i]);
    }

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
    DecToBin dtb = new DecToBin();
    for(int i=1;i<=63;i++)
    {
    System.out.print(i+"-> ");
    dtb.printBinaryFormat(i);
    System.out.print(" \n");
    }

    }
```

Now i want to give condition on the binary numbers like

if(dtb.printBinaryFormat(i)%100000==1)

it is showing error, now how to convert the printed form into int so that I could check the condition?

Comment: `I want to print ..` -- ok.

Comment: Go ahead and print!:)

Comment: please I am a newbie in here don't give me negative votes

Comment: You haven't made it clear what you are stuck on, so are bound to get down votes. Are you stuck on printing? Finding binary conversions? Bit counting? What have you tried?

Comment: `it is showing error` what error is it showing? It is compile time error or runtime error?

Comment: compile time error ..void type not allowed here. so I changed it to
public int printBinaryFormat and then it's working. But I am not getting proper output.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code to get the required result.

package com.java;

public class BitManipulation {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
int val=0;
StringBuffer addedString=null;
System.out.println("card 1:-");

    for(int i=1;i<63;i++){
        addedString=new StringBuffer();
        val=i;
        char value = 0;
        if(Integer.toBinaryString(val).length()!=6)
            for(int j=6;j>Integer.toBinaryString(val).length();j--)
                addedString.append("0");
            addedString.append(Integer.toBinaryString(val));
        value = addedString.toString().charAt(addedString.toString().length()-1);
        if(value == '1'){
            System.out.println(val+"->"+addedString);   
        }
    }
    System.out.println("card 2:-");
    for(int i=1;i<63;i++){
        val=i;
        addedString=new StringBuffer();
        char value=0;
        if(Integer.toBinaryString(val).length()!=6)
            for(int j=6;j>Integer.toBinaryString(val).length();j--)
                addedString.append("0");
            addedString.append(Integer.toBinaryString(val));
        value = addedString.toString().charAt(addedString.toString().length()-2);
        if(value == '1'){
            System.out.println(val+"->"+addedString
                    );  
        }

    }
    System.out.println("card 6:-");
    for(int i=1;i<63;i++){
        val=i;
        addedString=new StringBuffer();
        if(Integer.toBinaryString(val).length()!=6)
            for(int j=6;j>Integer.toBinaryString(val).length();j--)
                addedString.append("0");
            addedString.append(Integer.toBinaryString(val));
        if (addedString.toString().startsWith("1")) {
            System.out.println(val+"->"+addedString.toString());
        }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: thank you so much bro :) I don't have reputation to vote up your solution

Comment: I have updated the code as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [pnathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2866531/pnathan). Finally I got the solution

```
    public class DecToBin {


public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int val=0;
        System.out.println("Card 1:-");
        for(int i=1;i<63;i++)
        {
        val=i;
        char value=(Integer.toBinaryString(val)).charAt(Integer.toBinaryString(val).length()-1);
            if(value == '1'){
            System.out.print(val+" ");   
        }
        System.out.println("\nCard 2:-");
        for(int i=1;i<63;i++)
        {
        val=i;
            if(Integer.toBinaryString(val).length() >= 2)
        {
         char value=(Integer.toBinaryString(val)).charAt(Integer.toBinaryString(val).length()-2);
    if(value == '1')
        {
         System.out.print(val+" ");   
        }
        }
        }
    System.out.println("\nCard 3:-");
        for(int i=1;i<63;i++)
        {
        val=i;
            if(Integer.toBinaryString(val).length() >= 3)
        {
         char value=(Integer.toBinaryString(val)).charAt(Integer.toBinaryString(val).length()-2);
    if(value == '1')
        {
         System.out.print(val+" ");   
        }
        }
        }
        System.out.println("\nCard 4:-");
        for(int i=1;i<63;i++)
        {
        val=i;
            if(Integer.toBinaryString(val).length() >= 4)
        {
         char value=(Integer.toBinaryString(val)).charAt(Integer.toBinaryString(val).length()-4);
    if(value == '1')
        {
         System.out.print(val+" ");   
        }
        }
        }
        System.out.println("\nCard 5:-");
        for(int i=1;i<63;i++)
        {
        val=i;
            if(Integer.toBinaryString(val).length() >= 5)
        {
         char value=(Integer.toBinaryString(val)).charAt(Integer.toBinaryString(val).length()-5);
    if(value == '1')
        {
         System.out.print(val+" ");   
        }
        }
        }
        System.out.println("\nCard 6:-");
        for(int i=1;i<63;i++)
        {
        val=i;
            if(Integer.toBinaryString(val).length() >= 6)
        {
         char value=(Integer.toBinaryString(val)).charAt(Integer.toBinaryString(val).length()-6);
    if(value == '1')
        {
         System.out.print(val+" ");   
        }
        }
        }
    }
    }
```